# StringReader loaded with string yields nothing

Tags: vb.net, dataset, stringreader

```
Dim docVersion = XDocument.Load("L:\ProjectGroup\DocVersion.xml").ToString
result.Data = New DataSet
result.Data.ReadXml(New StringReader(docVersion))
```

So, at the end the dataset is empty (`Nothing`) as value. I tried using `StreamReader` as well, but I get `Illegal Characters in path` exception. Also some other stuff, that always brought me to exception. This is the way that went smooth, but yields no result... The `docVersion` string is initialized with data correctly. So I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I have a feeling you don't have option strict on... might be easier to just do result.Data.ReadXml("L:\ProjectGroup\DocVersion.xml") . Converting from a file to a xdocument to a string to a string reader is a bit of a mess.

Comment: I agree with your comment, however with or without Option Strict the code should work

Comment: Is it throwing an exception that you are ignoring?

Comment: @StevenDoggart , no I am not ignoring any exceptions. The ones I've written in my post are the ones I am getting. :)

Comment: @Steve , the_lotus, it still does not work... I don't get an exception, but the dataset is simply empty again.